# slider images loading very slow? if convert images png to gif images missing quality

Tags: image, png, loading

my website images loading very slow. i used PNG images. when i converted dose into GIF. images quality missing.

this is my code. is der any other soucre to decrease loading time.

```
<div class="fltyFloat" style="width:480px;height:349px;">
<div class="fltySlide" style="z-index: 1;" title="marketing">http://example.com/banners/marketing.png</div>
<div class="fltySlide" style="z-index: 2;" title="consultency">http://example.com/banners/consultency.png</div>
<div class="fltySlide" style="z-index: 3;" title="mobileapp">http://example.com/banners/mobileapp.png</div>
<div class="fltySlide" style="z-index: 4;" title="projectoutsoucring">http://example.com/banners/projectoutsoucring.png</div>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: Your code seems to be really fast, since there's nothing to load ;)

Comment: oho! really. thanks but why images loading very slow. client complain-ting again again. before loading images it's showing url. after dat images coming.

Comment: At first, your code has *in this case* nothing to do with bade page load time. Can you share us a link to your website?

Comment: i removed dat one. but  nw also coming like dat only.

Answer (score 0):

The images are not the problem, much more the facebook-connect and linkedin-widget... These scripts will be loaded from an external server and makes your page feeling slowly.

You can analyse your page-load time in the developer tools from google chrome or with firebug & yslow in firefox.